# Finding an optimal wage

Tags: calculus, optimization

Hiring a doctor costs $600$ dollars a day and hiring a nurse costs $200$ dollars a day. When d doctors and n nurses are hired, a clinic can serve $p=10d+nd+6n$ patients each day. Suppose a clinic budgets $9,000$ dollars a day for wages. What combination of nurses and doctors serves the greatest number of patients$?$

I'm not sure how to go about starting this problem.

Comment: Start by observing the equation $9000=600d+200n$. You now have a system of two equations and can maximize $p$.

Comment: Then solve for one variable in terms of another, plug in to the equation for $p$, take derivative, set = 0, and solve.

Answer (score 0):

We have to pay $600d + 200n$ in salaries per day. This can at most be $9000$, we may assume it will be exactly $9000$ (we obviously want to spend as much as possible, since there isn't any penalty in hiring more staff as long as we can afford it). This can be used to find an expression for $n$ given $d$. Or, said differently, a formula that given how many doctors we have hired on a given day, tells us how many nurses we can afford.

Finally, since we now know what $n$ is given $d$, we can swap out all the $n$'s in $p = 10d + nd + 6n$ with that one expression. Then we get an expression for $p$ using only $d$. This can be maximized using differentiation. If you for some reason have the formula specifically tailored to finding maxima and minima of second-degree polynomials, you may of course use that instead.